# Evaluate a primitive of $1/(x\ln x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a problem when I want to  find

$$\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}\ dx.$$

I don't know how to start with, can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Substitution: $u=\ln x$.

Comment: did you have a try ?

Comment: i just didn't know how to start with that. Iam newbie

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Please avoid `\displaystyle` as much as possible in titles.

Comment: @Did OK Sir. Noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{1}{x\ln x}\ dx=\int\frac{1}{\ln x}\ d(\ln x)=\ln|\ln x|+C\quad;\  x>0.
$$